# Проблемы с уничтожением сессии: Trying to destroy uninitialized session

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Пишу обработчик для кнопки выйти. Почему-то появляются проблемы с уничтожением сессии

```
<?
session_unset();
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');   
?>
```

> Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized  session in Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php on line 10
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php:1) in Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php on line 13

Answer (score 1):

session_start(); сначала нужно сделать

Comment: сделала..
опять 
    Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php:1) in Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php on line 4

    Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php:1) in Z:\home\registr\www\test\exit.php on line 13

Comment: У тебя значит есть вывод до того как ты используешь session_start(); 
Это или html код или просто незметный пробел/перевод строки

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?